# Try Catch function not returning values

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project and we have a custom Try Catch function and we are wrapping all our functions in it. The Try Catch function is this

```
function TryCatch(fxn) {
    try {
        //this is the function code that should be called
        fxn();
    } catch (err) {
        //an error occurred. attempt to log it back to the server
        TryLogError("", err, false);
    }
}
```

and we use it like this

```
function NewAdministratorDataToSubmit() {
    TryCatch(function () {
        var admin = {
            administratorName: $("#txtNewAdmin").val(),
            administratorPassword: $("#txtPassword").val(),
            administratorEmail: $("#txtAdministratorEmail").val(),
            administratorRoleID: $("#AdminRoles").val(),
            LoginUserName: $("#txtNewAdminUserName").val()
        };
        return admin;
    });
}
```

However, since we have it wrapped like that we are not getting the returned values.

I have tried doing this

```
function NewAdministratorDataToSubmit() {
    return {
            TryCatch(function () {
                var admin = {
                    administratorName: $("#txtNewAdmin").val(),
                    administratorPassword: $("#txtPassword").val(),
                    administratorEmail: $("#txtAdministratorEmail").val(),
                    administratorRoleID: $("#AdminRoles").val(),
                    LoginUserName: $("#txtNewAdminUserName").val()
                };
                return admin;
            });
        }
}
```

and that throws errors such as
at the passed function

> The Use Of a Keyword for an Identifier is invalid

and the closing of the

> TryCatch is Syntax Error

So I need to either fix the TryCatch function to return the values, or add a return to the functions that only return values. But not all functions return values

The TryCatch is used in ALL functions.

Any idea's?

Comment: Seems like a real PitA to have to wrap every piece of code this way, why not just use `window.onerror()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `return` statement.

```
function TryCatch(fxn) {
    try {
        return fxn(); // return the result of the function call
    } catch (err) {
        TryLogError("", err, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if the function that being passed does not return any values?

Comment: @Chris Functions always return a value. If there is no `return` statement, it returns `undefined`.

Comment: then you get `undefined`, the default value of javascript's function calls.

Comment: @Chris The missing return statement is not from the `fxn()` function. It is the return statement to return the result of executing `fxn()`.